# Defining constants with '.' token

Tags: c, constants

Why do I get an error if i define a constant like this?
‪

```
#‎define‬ F.NAME "First"
#define L.NAME "Second"
printf("%s %s\n", F.NAME, L.NAME);
```

But every thing runs smooth if i do this

```
#define F_NAME "First"
#define L_NAME "Second"
printf("%s %s\n", F_NAME, L_NAME);
```

Error I got is.

```
Warning: missing white space after the macro name
Error: expected expressions before '.' token
```

Why can't I define constants with '.' ?

Comment: Because this is not allowed.

Comment: Why do you think you *should not* get an error with it?  Similarly, do you expect `#define ~~;My*Goofy#$ymb0l~~ 42` should work?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a macro name must be an identifier, and identifiers can contain underscore, capital and small letters and digits only. Dot is used for structure's elements.

Comment: Additionally, identifiers must begin with a nondigit. `1foo` is not an identifier but `foo1` is

Answer (score 5):

Because the specification doesn't allow it. Periods and most other special characters (except `_`) are not allowed.

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct. There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.

From §6.4.2.1 of the C99 specification.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.` can not be used within a variable/identifier name.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because a macro name must be an identifier, and identifiers cannot contain the `.` character.